# Visual Studio 2010 extension smart tag functions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Where can I find an example of a Visual Studio 2010 extension that lets you put a smart tag on functions in a source code?

For example, if the cursor "stands" on a function name (and a function only), the user will be able to select my actions from the drop down menu (in addition to the existing operations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its any use to you at this late stage, but I used the MEF example [Walkthrough: Displaying SmartTags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee334190) on MSDN to guide me on creating a custom tag for my own functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing.  The closest thing I've found so far is a helper in a Visual Studio extension library called DXCore (DXCore is a library in CodeRush: http://www.skorkin.com/2011/05/dxcore-components-smarttagprovider/ )

You have to pay for coderush, but DXCore is a free library.  I found this thread on how to get it: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/76328/261446.aspx (you install the trial edition of CodeRush, and that includes the free dxcore library).